# Setting a resource block parameter based on a boolean

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a Terraform project for Aurora PostgreSQL and would like to have a variable defined whether it's serverless or not, if possible at all. For example:

1. variables.tf:

   `variable "serverless" {type = bool}`
2. terraform.tfvars:

   `serveless = "true"`
3. main.tf (pseudo code):

   ```
   resource "aws_rds_cluster" "db_cluster" {
   ...

   if var.serveless == true ? 
       serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
         max_capacity = 16
         min_capacity = 0.5
       }
   : []
   ```

If the variable is true - set the serverless code, otherwise - don't include it at all.

Comment: You can use the `dynamic` block with `for_each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a good candidate to use `for_each` [1] and `dynamic` [2] block combined. In that case, you would have something like:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  dynamic "serverlessv2_scaling_configuration" {
    for_each = var.serveless ? [1] : []
    content {
      max_capacity = var.max_capacity
      min_capacity = var.min_capacity
    }
  }
}
```

Take care also about the note for Aurora Severless:

> serverlessv2_scaling_configuration configuration is only valid when `engine_mode` is set to `provisioned`

So you might also want to use the ternary expression in that case.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Comment: Thank you! I also had to set instance_class appropriately, in addition to engine_mode:
instance_class = var.serverless ? "db.serverless" : var.instance_class